# making calls to iter and next when iterating through a generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

i am writing a function that takes an iterator an int and a padding at the end to be added if what was iterated through has less than n values.. I am able to get the function working completely for the iterator parameters that are not of type generator and if it is it would raise the typerror exception where I would be working on the generator in that block of code. The problem is I am able to yield all values inside the generator but I have not been able to figure out a way to add the padding at the end because the outer for loop interferes. I need to implement this by making calls to iter and next which I have been playing around with but it has not been working... Here is the function ill explain

```
def n_with_pad(iterable,n,pad=None):

    for i in range(n):   
        try:
            yield iterable[i]

        except IndexError:
            yield pad

        except TypeError:
            for i in iterable: 
                yield i
```

so I were to call this function as follow

```
for i n_with_pad('function',3):
    print(i,end=' ')
```

i would print: 'f' 'u' 'n'

but adding the pad with iterables that have less than n values would print as follows

```
for i n_with_pad('abcdefg',10,'?'):
    print(i,end=' ')
```

'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '?', '?' and '?'

for the second call I am able to get up to 
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' 
with the code I have so far but cannot seem to add the ??? to satisfy n-values

Comment: it works fine for the most part but once it takes a generator object after raising the typeerror exception I am trying to figure out how to add whatever is passed in for pad to satisfy a total number of n-values specified in the parameter

Comment: Are you explicitly trying to avoid `itertools`?  Because this is a one-liner with `chain` and `islice`.  Maybe `repeat` thrown in for good measure, depending on exactly what you want.

Comment: yes I am trying to prevent making calls to ANY other functions

Answer (score 1):

I see no benefit to trying the `__getitem__` approach and falling back to the iterator protocol.  Just use the iterable, that's even the name of the variable!

```
def n_with_pad(iterable,n,pad=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for _ in range(n):   
        yield next(it,pad)
```

demo:

```
''.join(n_with_pad('function',3,pad='?'))
Out[6]: 'fun'

''.join(n_with_pad('function',10,pad='?'))
Out[7]: 'function??'
```